# How to read data from dynamically created textbox in jsp using jQuery.each()

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets

I have textbox that created dynamically in jsp. Then, I want to take the data inside and send it to servlet using jQuery.each(). The problem is, it only takes top textbox data only and not even read the rest. Can someone point out the problems.Btw, english not my native.

Dynamically created textbox,

```
 <table>

    <c:forEach items="${questList}" var="quest" varStatus="status"> 

        <tr id="looping">
            <td><c:out value="${status.index + 1}" ></c:out></td>
            <td>${quest.questText}</td>
            <td><textarea id="resp" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea></td>
            <td><textarea id="qId" >${quest.questId}</textarea></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
  </table>
```

and my jQuery code

```
$('#looping').each(function(i){
            var res = $('#resp').val();
            var qId = $('#qId').val();

            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                data:{
                    res: res,
                    qId: qId,
                },
            url:'Response'

            })
        });
```

Comment: ID's are unique, you seem to be creating rows in a loop, with all the same ID's. Use classes instead, and the problem solves itself.

Comment: Is that wrong? I thought I would get the data inside. Or it is confusing to process later?

Comment: Isn't .each() supposedly get the data with the ID's?

Comment: Yes, it's wrong, that's why I typed it? Javascript expects there to be only **one** ID with any given name, which is why it only gets the first one

Comment: Oh I see. Then how I can implement .each() for dynamically created textbox?

Comment: You use classes instead, here -> https://jsfiddle.net/baz40yxu/

Comment: I have tested it. It through the loops until the end but only takes data on the first row for each loop.

Comment: One more question @adeneo, why should use class instead of id?

Comment: Because you're generating elements in a loop, and all of those elements ends up with the same ID, and you can only use an ID **once**, hence why it's called a "**unique** indentifier".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your code to look like this, because when trying to get data by targeting the field with an ID selector will only return the data from the first field. So change your code to look like this:

```
('#looping').each(function(i){
        var res = $(this).find('#resp').val();
        var qId = $(this).find('#qId').val();

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            data:{
                res: res,
                qId: qId,
            },
        url:'Response'

        })
    });
```

Comment: Your solution works but with some modification like @adeneo suggest above that ID should be change to CLASS. Thanks dude!! Both of you.